# Мультимножество для проекции: выражение реляционной алгебры

Tags: база-данных

Это упражнение 5.3.3 (b) из книги "Системы баз данных: полный курс" (Гарсия-Молина, Ульман, Уидом).

Для следующей схемы (bore - калибр):

```
Classes (class, type, country, numGuns, bore, displacement)
Ships (name, class, launched)
```

Выглядит оно так:

> Напишите выражение реляционной алгебры, позволяющее получить мультимножество значений калибров орудий отдельных судов (не классов); иными словами, если *n* судов обладает орудиями калибра *b*, результат должен содержать *n* кортежей, содержащих значение *b*.

Насколько я понимаю, предполагается, что нельзя использовать оператор проекции для мультимножеств, т.е. ответ вроде [image: введите сюда описание изображения] не подойдет. В то же время оператор проекции для множеств также не подойдет, т.к. удалит дубликаты значений калибра.